# Captura de video en negro con openCv

Tags: python, opencv

Según un tutorial este código me sirve para hacer captura de video, tambien pasarlo a escala de grises.

Sin embargo, cuando lo corro, la visualización del video me sale en negro y ademas el video que se guarda no tiene casi peso (4kb).

¿Alguien me podría dar una mano?

```
info sistema: Python 2.7 en IDE spyder. 64bits
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Jul 21 13:22:58 2017

@author: 
"""

import cv2
import numpy as np

    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0);
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out=cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(640,480))
    while True: 
          ret , frame = cap.read()
          gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
          out.write(frame)
          cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
          try:
              out.write(frame)
          except:
              print ('ERROR - Not writting to file')
              cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
          if cv2.waitKey(0):
              break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    del(cap)
```

Comment: Hola Cristian, bienvenido a [es.so]. Mientras alguien que sepa de [tag:opencv] te contesta, lee el [tour] donde verás explicado el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Tambien puedes leer [ask] donde se explica cómo debe formularse una pregunta para que se considere *de calidad*.  Un saludo

Comment: Cristian te he contestado pero deberias hacer caso a lois6b y explicar cual debe ser el comportamiento de tu programa si quieres obtener respuestas más apropiadas a tu problema real. No queda claro si quieres grabar/mostrar en tiempo real en color o en escala de grises. Deberias aclarar esto. Por otro lado, si te mostrara algún error en la terminal debes aportarlo. Recuerda formatear adecuadamente el código y respetar la identación, cuando agreges código seleccionalo y pulsa el botón `{}` del editor o `Ctrl+k` para que quede formateado como código. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

El único problema que hay en el código (además de la identación) es que solo capturas un fotograma, esperas a que se pulse una tecla y cuando es pulsada sales del programa. Tu vídeo será un solo fotograma.

La línea en cuestión es:

```
if cv2.waitKey(0):
```

El parámetro pasado a `waitKey` es el delay, el tiempo en milisegundos que debe esperar a ver si se pulsa una tecla antes de continuar. Un valor de 0 indica que espere eternamente.

El siguiente código es perfectamente funcional usando OpenCv 3:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

while True: 
      ret, frame = cap.read()

      try:
          cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
          out.write(frame)

      except:
          print ('ERROR - Not writting to file')
          gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
          cv2.imshow('frame', gray)

      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
del(cap)
```

> **Nota:** Lo que este script hace es capturar y grabar el vídeo en color, si por alguna razón no puede guardar, entonces muestra el vídeo pero en escala de grises. El programa termina al pulsar <kbd>q</kbd>.

Comment: gracias, ya me corre pero no guarda el video de ninguna manera, lo que pasa es que lo necesito desarrollar un identificador de figura redondas a partir de un video. Sin embargo, lo estoy haciendo en rapsberry y su procesador es muy lento, por eso lo paso a grises directamente.

Comment: Cristian para ir descartando cosas, ¿Si intentas guardar el video en color te guarda algo? ¿Tienes instalado ffmpeg? Quiero recordar que XVID falla si se le pasa una imágen de un solo canal, prueba con H264.

Comment: si, guarda algo pero de muy poco peso aprox... 4kb, respecto al ffmpeg es un codec? ya lo intente con H264 sin embargo no me lo reproduce.....

Comment: En cuanto a lo de FFmpeg mirate https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg. Creo que es un tema de codec, el problema es que nunca he usado openCV en un raspberry y creo que tiene sus peculiaridades... Prueba a usar MJPG en vez de XVID : `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')` y a guardar el video en color a ver que pasa.